# Use array and find multiple strings using the below code in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

How to use array in below code to find multiple strings?

```
Sub Replace18()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim rws As Long
        rws = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 3
        Set rng = Rows("3:3").Find(What:="quantity", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "20"
            rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rws).FillDown
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another variant (based on `@Jeeped` answer)

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object, k As Variant, S$, rws&, x&, Rng As Range
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    S = "Lorem,ipsum,dolor,amet,consectetur,adipiscing,elit,Mauris," & _
        "facilisis,rutrum,faucibus,Sed,euismod,orci,rhoncus,tincidunt,elit,eros"
    For Each k In Split(S, ",")
        If Not Dic.exists(k) Then Dic.Add k, Nothing
    Next k
    rws = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 3
    x = [3:3].Find("*", , , xlByColumns, , xlPrevious).Column
    For Each Rng In Range([A3], Cells(3, x))
        If Dic.exists(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "20"
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rws).FillDown
        End If
    Next Rng
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test2()
    Dim Dic As Object, k As Variant, S$, rws&, x&, Rng As Range
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    S = "Lorem,ipsum,dolor,amet,consectetur,adipiscing,elit,Mauris," & _
        "facilisis,rutrum,faucibus,Sed,euismod,orci,rhoncus,tincidunt,elit,eros"
    For Each k In Split(S, ",")
        If Not Dic.exists(k) Then Dic.Add k, ""
    Next k
    rws = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    x = [3:3].Find("*", , , xlByColumns, , xlPrevious).Column
    For Each Rng In Range([A3], Cells(3, x))
        If Dic.exists(Rng.Value) Then
            Range(Cells(Rng.Row + 1, Rng.Column), Cells(rws, Rng.Column)).Value = "20"
        End If
    Next Rng
End Sub
```

Comment: HI vasily, Thanks for the answer. Can guide me how to fix the range issue. As you see i am using a static range. I want it to be dynamic and use the first search terms range. how can i do that?

Comment: Hello @Tarun Aryan, I have already posted variant with using dynamic range of columns, this `x = [3:3].Find("*", , , xlByColumns, , xlPrevious).Column`  will give the last column in range `[3:3]`, and `Range([A3], Cells(3, x))` will give you the dynamic range

Comment: and if you want "find the last row used no matter what column it is" then you can use this `Cells.Find("*", , , xlByRows, , xlPrevious).Row`, so you need just replace `rws = ...`     with `rws = Cells.Find("*", , , xlByRows, , xlPrevious).Row`

Answer (score 3):

Set up a variant array and cycle through them.

```
Sub Replace18()
    Dim rng As Range, rws As Long, w As Long, vWHATs As Variant

    vWHATs = Array("Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", _
                   "elit", "Mauris", "facilisis", "rutrum", "faucibus", "Sed", _
                   "euismod", "orci", "rhoncus", "tincidunt", "elit", "eros")

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")   '<~~set this worksheet reference properly!
        rws = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row - 3

        For w = LBound(vWHATs) To UBound(vWHATs)
            Set rng = .Rows(3).Find(What:=vWHATs(w), LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                'just fill then all at once
                rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rws, 1) = "20"
            End If
        Next w
    End With
End Sub
```

I've modified your search for the 'last row' to include all columns with the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) using the [xlCellTypeLastCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) option. This works best with a properly referenced parent worksheet which I've included in a  [With ... End With](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) block. All cell and range references within this block should carry a period (aka `.` or *full stop*) as a prefix to note that they belong to the worksheet referenced in the With ... End With. This includes `.Rows(3)` just as the `.Find` uses a prefix period to note that it is referencing `Rows(3)`.

---

Comment: Hi jeeped that worked. Learned arrays today thanks to you. I have another question in the above macro i am using a static range which is not always working. Can you tell me how to make it dynamic so that the range can always be the cloumns with highest no of rows?

Comment: Currently you are looking for the last populated value in column A to get the 'last row'. Do you just want to get the 'last row' no matter what column might extend down further than column A? btw, did you want something different to fill the columns for other strings?

Comment: Yes  i want to find the last row used no matter what column it is!

Comment: That should take care of it. Mind that you keep the worksheet clean and do not gain a rogue 'last cell' down at the 1,048,576th row of the worksheet.