# How to bold text append to excel cells

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I want to make `test` variable bold, but I can't find the sample code for this problem.

```
string test = "computer"; //this should be bold
worksheet_Main.Cells[25, "b"] = "bla bla bla" + test + "bla bla bla";
```

Comment: [add-html-text-in-excel-cell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/364ab1e9-861e-4296-92fc-0c85eeb2cb2a/add-html-text-in-excel-cell?forum=exceldev)

Comment: In VBA this is [Count and Highlight keywords within phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860792/count-and-highlight-keywords-within-phrases/32878493#32878493) and [Use array and find multiple strings using the below code in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106818/use-array-and-find-multiple-strings-using-the-below-code-in-vba/34107107#34107107). You should be able to translate to C# from there.

Comment: What excel package are you using?

Comment: @AdeoluwaSimeon Excel 2016